# Uniform convergence on a compact

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the sequence of function $f_n (x)=nx^{n^2}$ for $0\le x\le 1$ uniform converge in the interval $[0,a]$ for $0<a<1$, but the convergence isn't uniform on $[0,1].$

Hello :). Can help me with the converge? I think that first can see the pointwise convergence, truth?

Comment: The sequence converges to $0$ for $x<0$, and diverges to $\infty$ for $x=1$.  Since the limit function is discintinuous, the sequence cannot converge uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Recall $\lim_{n\to \infty} a^n = 0$ for $a \in (0,1)$. This should help for uniform convergence on $(0,1)$. Uniform convergence $\Rightarrow$ pointwise convergence, hence if $f_n$ does not converge pointwise for some $x$ it does not converge uniformly. For $[0,1]$, where does $f_n$ go if $x=1$?

As a side note, it's worth mentioning that we had to restrict to $[0,a]$ (i.e. closed intervals) as $x$ may not converge uniformly on $[0,1)$. Check why this is true yourself using the definition of uniform convergence.